# App crashes when trying to re-open. MIT App Inventor

Tags: android, crash, app-inventor

So I made two apps until the moment and both have the same problem. One is a complicated user interface and the other is as simple as it gets, only one button. But yet when I exit both apps and try to open them again a message comes up: "Unfortunately, *AppName* has stopped." I have no clue as to what causes this and its whats keeping me from going public. Any help?

Summary of actions that bring up the problem:

1)Start app by tapping icon in device,
2)Use app normally
3)Exit app by pressing "HomeButton"
4)Tap app icon in device (again)
5)Error Appears. *("Unfortunately, *AppName* has stopped.")*
6)App opens again by itself after the error message.

Thanks anticipated!

Comment: Whenever you get the "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped" message and post a question about it be sure to include the logcat stack trace so we have an idea of what went wrong and can help. As of now there is no way to help because you didn't include the log and didn't include any code either.

Comment: This is app inventor, I dont know if I can get you that info. How can I include a log?

Comment: I'm not familiar with App Inventor and maybe there is an easier way to figure out the reason the application crashed. However, it says [here](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/learn/live-development-testing-and-debugging.html) that you might still be able to get the logcat output to see what is causing the crash under "The Android Log and adb(Advanced)". Unfortunately the log might not be as helpful since the app was created with app inventor but it still might give you a better idea of what went wrong.

Comment: My guess is, you do not switch screens correctly... see here how to do it: [The recommended method of switching screens in App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I solved the problem. The thing appears to be that I was using the back button to exit the app and then open it again and that caused it to crash. The back button was not being adressed. I gave it a close app command and it stopped crashing.